# how to get the remainder and calculate the price in ruby?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, module, conditional-statements

how should I write this in Ruby??

- A single book is $35.00
- books in lots of 4 for $112.00 (so if someone buys 9 books, it would cost $259).

this is what I could write:

```
book_price = 35.00 * quantity

if quantity == 4  
    book_price = 112.00
elsif quantity > 4
    book_price = (quantity / 4) * 112.00
    book_price += (quantity % 4) * 35.00
end

puts "you spend a total of $#{book_price} on books.
```

Comment: You should choose better variable names. I assume `user_input` is actually `quantity`. In any language, you'd integer divide the quantity of books by 4, multiply that result by 112. Take the remainder of the total book quantity when divided by 4 and multiply that by 35, then take the sum of those two operations. `total_price = (user_input/4)*112.00 + (user_input % 4)*35.00`.

Comment: Hi, can you brief it more. are you trying to achieve a `flat discount` and does `user_input` means the quantity?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This has a homework smell to it: "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)". What is your code not doing that you want it to do? Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages for more information about how to improve your question.

Comment: There's no reason, in your current implementation, for the `if` statement. The `else` portion of your `if` will calculate the correct price even if `quantity` is equal to 4.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Numeric#divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) to find the number of 4-book bundles and leftover single books, then use standard arithmetic to compute the price for the bundles, the leftovers, and finally the total price.

Breaking your computation up into separate expressions gives you the opportunity to use variables to give self-explanatory names to those sub-expressions, and to allow your code to "tell a story".

It is also always a good idea to test your code.

```rb
def book_price(quantity)
  single_book_price =  35
  bundle_price      = 112

  bundle_size       =   4

  bundles_quantity, leftover_quantity = quantity.divmod(bundle_size)

  bundles_price   = bundles_quantity  * bundle_price
  leftovers_price = leftover_quantity * single_book_price

  bundles_price + leftovers_price
end

require 'test/unit'
class BookPriceTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  data do
    [
      [0, 0],
      [1, 35],
      [3, 105],
      [4, 112],
      [8, 224],
      [5, 147],
      [7, 217],
      [9, 259],
  ].each_with_object({}) do |(quantity, price), data_set|
      data_set["#{quantity} books should cost #{price}"] = [quantity, price]
    end
  end
  def test_that_the_price_for_QUANTITY_books_is_PRICE
    quantity, price = data
    assert_equal price, book_price(quantity)
  end
end
```

Running this gives:

```
Loaded suite ./book_price
Started
........
Finished in 0.00079 seconds.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8 tests, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10126.58 tests/s, 10126.58 assertions/s
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you might do it

```
def price(num_books)
  full_price = 35.00
  sum = (num_books / 4) * 112.00 # bulk discounted price per 4
  sum += (num_books % 4) * full_price
end

price(9)
=>259.0
price(3)
=>105
price(4)
=>112
```

Comment: thank you so much. not sure why I get $287 when the quantity is 9( i don't want to write a function)

Comment: book_price = 35.00 * quantity

    if quantity == 4  
        book_price = 112.00
    elsif quantity > 4
        book_price = (quantity / 4) * 112.00
        book_price += (quantity % 4) * 35.00
    end

puts "you spend a total of $#{book_price} on books.

Comment: Consider using `divmod`, `zip` and `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

We can get this using ternary operator and remainder zero logic.

```
quantity = 4
discount = quantity/4 * 112
rem = quantity%4

book_price = (rem == 0 ? discount : discount + rem * 35)
puts "you spend a total of $#{book_price} on books."

you spend a total of $112 on books.
  => nil
```